# Display persons based on view

Tags: column, view, person

I have a **Person column** I'd like to display in some **view** as just *name*, some other *with presence* and again in some other place with *picture and details*. Does anybody know a workaround to get it (unless creating new person columns and copying there the data with a WF)?

Thanks,

Comment: No, I dont't think this is possible other than alternate workaround....

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint Designer Data View Webpart to achieve your functionality.

Just Add DVWP on the page select the field you need to display. You can follow blogs to achieve same

http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2010/03/02/unlocking-the-mysteries-of-data-view-web-part-xsl-tags-part-12-miscellaneous-person-or-group-columns-aspx/

http://www.glynblogs.com/2010/11/displaying-a-users-picture-in-the-data-view-web-part.html